# Pandas: Selecting and modifying dataframe based on even more complex criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I was looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38802675/create-bool-mask-from-filter-results-in-pandas) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315452/selecting-with-complex-criteria-from-pandas-dataframe) threads, and though my question is not so different, it has a few differences. I have a dataframe full of `floats`, that I want to replace by strings. Say:

```
      A     B       C
 A    0     1.5     13
 B    0.5   100.2   7.3
 C    1.3   34      0.01
```

To this table I want to replace by several criteria, but only the first replacement works:

```
df[df<1]='N' # Works
df[(df>1)&(df<10)]#='L' # Doesn't work
df[(df>10)&(df<50)]='M'  # Doesn't work
df[df>50]='H'  # Doesn't work
```

If I instead do the selection for the 2nd line based on `float`, still doesn't work:

```
((df.applymap(type)==float) & (df<10) & (df>1)) #Doesn't work
```

I was wondering how to apply `pd.DataFrame().mask` in here, or any other way. How should I solve this?

Alternatively, I know I may read column by column and apply the substitutions on each series, but this seems a bit counter productive

Edit: Could anyone explain why the 4 simple assignments above do not work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html)

### Copy

```
labels = np.array(list('NLMH'))
breaks = np.array([1, 10, 50])
pd.DataFrame(
    labels[breaks.searchsorted(df.values)].reshape(df.shape),
    df.index, df.columns)

   A  B  C
A  N  L  M
B  N  H  L
C  L  M  N
```

---

### In Place

```
labels = np.array(list('NLMH'))
breaks = np.array([1, 10, 50])
df[:] = labels[breaks.searchsorted(df.values)].reshape(df.shape)
df

   A  B  C
A  N  L  M
B  N  H  L
C  L  M  N
```

---

### Chained pure Pandas approach with `pandas.DataFrame.mask`

Deprecated since version 0.21

```
df.mask(df.lt(1), 'N').mask(df.gt(1) & df.lt(10), 'L') \
  .mask(df.gt(10) & df.lt(50), 'M').mask(df.gt(50), 'H')

   A  B  C
A  N  L  M
B  N  H  L
C  L  M  N
```

Answer (score 12):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with `DataFrame` constructor:

```
m1 = df < 1
m2 = (df>1)&(df<10)
m3 = (df>10)&(df<50)
m4 = df>5

vals = list('NLMH')

df = pd.DataFrame(np.select([m1,m2,m3,m4], vals), index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
print (df)
   A  B  C
A  N  L  M
B  N  H  L
C  L  M  N
```

Comment: ah! I was really thinking about doing this, but wasn't sure  how to use the 4 rules in a mask (I learned about `mask` from your previous answers on my posts a while back)

Answer (score 7):

By using `pd.cut`

```
pd.cut(df.stack(),[-1,1,10,50,np.inf],labels=list('NLMH')).unstack()
Out[309]: 
   A  B  C
A  N  L  M
B  N  H  L
C  L  M  N
```