# Error ModuleNotFoundError: No Module Named 'api' When Running Python Code

Tags: python-3.x

I have a problem when running my Python Code, I get a Traceback Error even though I have installed the module pip-api.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import target
import pip_api
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get("http://web.archive.org/web/20070826230746/http://www.bbmf.co.uk/july07.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'lxml')
table = soup.find_all('table')[0]

df = pd.read_html(str(table))
df = df[1]
df = df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0])
df = df.iloc[2:]
df.head(15)

Southport = df[
    (
        df['Location'].str.contains('- Display') & 
        df['Lancaster'] == '' & 
        df['Dakota'] == 'D' & 
        df['Spitfire'] == 'S' & 
        df['Hurricane'] == 'H'
    )
] | df[
    (
        df['Location'].str.contains('- Display') & 
        df['Lancaster'] == '' & 
        df['Dakota'] == 'D' & 
        df['Spitfire'] == 'S' &
        df['Hurricane'] == ''
    )
] | df[
    (
        df['Location'].str.contains('- Display') & 
        df['Lancaster'] == '' & 
        df['Dakota'] == 'D' & 
        df['Spitfire'] == 'SS' &
        df['Hurricane'] == ''
    )
]
```

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-1e8f3727cc23> in <module>
      1 import pandas as pd
      2 import requests
----> 3 import ops
      4 import target
      5 import api

c:\python37\lib\site-packages\ops\__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from api import *
      2 from compound import *
      3 from target import *
      4 
      5 __all__ = ["api", "compound", "target"]

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api'
```

The following Thread explains the aim of my Python Code :-

[Python code line is too long and needs breaking up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56692009/python-code-line-is-too-long-and-needs-breaking-up/56692790?noredirect=1#comment99952379_56692790)

Any help would be appreciated

Eddie

Comment: How did you install it, where is it installed, and what is your `sys.path`?

Comment: Also I'm pretty sure the only relevant line in your code is the `import ops`, which is causing the error.

Comment: You never use `ops`, so remove that import

Comment: The Traceback error is less after removing import ops, but still says :- ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api'

Comment: To install I typed in the directory C:\Python37\Scripts   pip install pip-api

Comment: It is installed in  C:\Python37\Lib\site-packages

Comment: I made a mistake I should have typed :- import pip_api

Comment: I now get a long Traceback Error ending :- TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [object] array with a scalar of type [bool]

Comment: Ah, so it was just a typo, and `import pip_api` resolved it. Glad you figured it out! You can ask a new question about the TypeError, but please make a [mcve] first.

Comment: Many thanks for your info wjandrea, I have done what you said to do ))