# Split Dataframe into two based on null and blocked values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and want to split the dataframe into two based on multiple columns.

df should have all rows without null column and status yes. Rest should be on df_null

```
df = vehicle.csv

Status  Country City     Year 
Yes     USA     New York 2001
Yes     Canada           2001
Yes     France  Paris    
No              Rio      1843
No      Germany Berlin   2008
Yes                      2004

# df_null has all the rows with null in the three columns
df_null = df[~df[['Country', 'City', 'Year']].notnull().all(1)]

# df has all columns with not null and status = yes
df = df[df[['Country', 'City', 'Year']].notnull().all(1)]

df = df.loc[df['Status'] == 'Yes']

result = pd.concat([df, df_null])
```

Row with Germany isnt on result dataframe because its filtered out by `Status = Yes`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by making a [binary mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38802675) with the code below:

```
# Import Data
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ["Yes", "USA", "New York", 2001],
        ["Yes", "Canada", None, 2001],
        ["Yes", "France", "Paris", None],
        ["No", None, "Rio", 1843],
        ["No", "Germany", "Berlin", 2008],
        ["Yes", None, None, 2004],
    ],
    columns=["Status", "Country", "City", "Year"],
)

# Create Mask
valid_rows = (df[["Country", "City", "Year"]].notnull().all(1)) & (df["Status"] == "Yes")

df_null = df[~valid_rows]  # Filter by inverse of mask
df = df[valid_rows]  # Filter by mask
```

This outputs for df as:

|  | Status | Country | City | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Yes | USA | New York | 2001 |

And for df_null as:

|  | Status | Country | City | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Yes | Canada |  | 2001 |
| 2 | Yes | France | Paris | nan |
| 3 | No |  | Rio | 1843 |
| 4 | No | Germany | Berlin | 2008 |
| 5 | Yes |  |  | 2004 |

Comment: this removes the whole columns not the rows

Comment: Sorry, I missed the .all(1) method. It should work fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
# Import pandas library 
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
# initialize list of lists 
data = [['Yes', 'USA', 'New York' ,2001 ],['Yes', 'Canada','',2001 ], ['Yes', 'France', 'Paris' ,'' ], ['No','' , 'Rio' ,1843 ],['No', 'Germany', 'Berlin' ,2008 ],['Yes', '', '' ,2004 ]] 
# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["Status","Country","City","Year"]) 

# Adding filter conditions. 
df_new =  df.replace('', np.nan)
df_new = df_new[df_new.Status == 'Yes'].dropna()
df_null =df[(~df.isin(df_new))].dropna()
# Printing the two dataframes
print(df_new)
print(df_null)
```

Comment: not exactly I want to label the rows which the filter is based on because I have multiple columns with null values which is relevant

Comment: may you provide us with a desired output ? that will be really helpful to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

if your problem statement is to split the dataframe based on Null values then simply use below code.

DF_null = processed_records_DF[processed_records_DF['ColumnName'].isnull()]

DF_not_null = processed_records_DF[processed_records_DF['ColumnName'].notnull()]