# python data search with list condition notation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list

I see a lot of tutorials, data science, and ML related stuff, doing something like this in Pytohn

> data[data["total_savings"] < 400000]

so they can search the list faster, rather than using the `map()` function

***what's that??*** and how to use it?

and what is it called so I can search for it?

Comment: it is a kind of filtering on the data i.e dataframe, which means get all the rows from data where  `total_savings`  is less than `400000`, see examples: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/selecting-rows-in-pandas-dataframe-based-on-conditions/

Comment: This would generally be called masking: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38802912/9811508

Comment: This notation is used with pandas dataframes

Comment: This is called [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)